# Scoping Hilt dependencies in a single Activity application

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I have a single Activity Android Application that uses Jetpack Compose, Hilt and Firebase. In this application, Hilt is used to inject a `Repository` Singleton, which itself injects `FirebaseAuth` and `FirebaseFirestore` in order to get data associated with the current user.

```
// MyMainActivity.kt

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyMainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApp()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MyApp() {
    NavHost(
        navController = rememberNavController(),
        startDestination = "login"
    ) {
        composable("login") {
            LoginScreen(viewModel: LoginViewModel = hiltViewModel())
        }
        composable("home") {
            HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel())
        }
    }
}
```

```
// HomeViewModel.kt

@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: Repository
) { ... }
```

```
// MyAppModule.kt

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseAuth() = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    @Provides
    fun provideFirebaseFirestore() = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    ...

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRepository(
        firestore: FirebaseFirestore,
        auth: FirebaseAuth,
    ) = Repository(firestore, auth)

    ...
}
```

When a user logs out of the application, they are directed back to a Composable `LoginScreen` that exists within a `NavHost` within `MyApp()`. However, when logging in with a different user, the old user's data is still currently visible on the `HomeScreen`. This occurs because, as the Application's Hilt Module is scoped to the `MainActivity` (and the main activity is never destroyed), the `Repository` cannot been re-made with the new `FirebaseAuth` instance containing new user information.

There is a possibility of having a 2-Activity Appliction. An `UnauthenticatedActivity` and `AuthenticatedActivity` which would allow the `Repository` to be scoped to the `AuthenticatedActivity`, and be remade whenever a user logs in. However, the simplicity of the single Activity approach has been great so far and it feels like there should be a way to scope dependencies to Composables, or at least there should be a way to force the Hilt Module to rebuild itself within the Activity?

Essentially, is there a way to ensure that the Hilt Module rebuilds the `Repository` Singleton when a user logs back in, whilst also keeping the Application to its single Activity architecture?

Answer (score 0):

if your home and login page have different viewModels then you can use the @viewModelScoped annotation on your providesRepository function to scope the to HomeViewModel.

```
    @Singleton
    @ViewModelScoped
    @Provides
    fun provideRepository(
        firestore: FirebaseFirestore,
        auth: FirebaseAuth,
    ) = Repository(firestore, auth)
```